# How do I get a random image from a folder? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

Currently, I do it like this, but I would like to be redirected to a random image in the folder ./images/ which all look something like "646673.png".
at the end, you should be brought randomly to a page that looks similar to this one: "https://image.com/images/646673.png"

```
    const images = [
        "http://www.google.com",
        "http://www.stackoverflow.com",
        "http://www.example.com",
        "http://www.youtube.com"
    ]


    var i = Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length);
    window.location.href = images[i]
```

As more and more images are added, it would be easier this way, so I don't have to enter each image as a link separately, I hope this is possible somehow

Comment: Refer to this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemDirectoryEntry/getDirectory

Comment: Usually on your server you will have a folder public_html.  Is your image file somewhere below that folder in the directory structure?